# Why can't I echo out a variable from an array?

Tags: php

I'm sorry if this has been asked, but I have no idea what to search for to find an answer.

I'm just starting to learn PHP and am doing a simple tutorial where I'm "logging into" a data base (just checking to see if the email and password match what is stored no actual session is being created).

I have this code:

```
<?php

include("connectToDb.php");
$loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
$loginPassword = $_POST['loginPassword'];

$query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$loginEmail'");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrows != 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $dbemail = $row['email'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        $dbfirstname = $row['firstName'];
    }
    if($loginEmail == $dbemail)
    {
        if ($loginPassword == $dbpassword)
        {
            echo "Hi ".$row['firstName'].", you are now logged in.";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "login failed.";
        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

But the $row['firstName'] in the echo statement prints as a blank string: "Hi , you are now logged in.". If I use the exact same code but repalce $row['firstName'] with $dbfirstname in the echo statement, I get a properly formatted message "Hi Jason, you are now logged in.".

Those two variables are supposed to be the same... why does one work while the other does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the control flow:

You have the while loop `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))` - so you assign a new value to `$row` and test it. If it evaluates to false (i.e. no more rows), you break the loop.

This implies, that after the loop `$row` no longer has valid content. Your stored values (e.g. `$dbfirstname`) are from the previous iteration of the loop and thus contain valid data.

Comment: Yup. That seems pretty obvious now. That's what I get for pasting code from a tutorial without thinking it through all the way... Is there any particular reason that the tutorial writer would have "needed" to use a while loop? Couldn't he have just assigned $row and moved on? The rest of this code assumes that there was only a single found instance of the email address... Anyway thanks for your quick response.